# How to enable .com key for UITextField keyboard?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How do I enable the ".com" key on the keyboard for UITextField? As an example, this key shows up when user clicks on the navigation item for the apple browser. Is there a web-specific keyboard layout I could specify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick: (replace "myTextField" with the name of your text field, of course):

```
myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
```

See also: the [UITextInputTraits](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html) protocol, which controls things like keyboard layout and autocorrection.